# Python class has not attribute "x", using odometry data in a action server

Tags: python, ros, odometry

I'm struggling making an action server where I have to use the subscribe to odometry data to use it in the action callback. I managed to get the pose data and I know its okay cause I have printed it inside the subscriber callback. My problem is that when I want to use this data outside I get this error:

```
ERROR] [1672904624.503538, 1251.206000]: Exception in your execute callback: 'move_turtle' object has no attribute 'xOdom'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/simulations/public_sim_ws/src/all/actionlib/actionlib/src/actionlib/simple_action_server.py", line 289, in executeLoop
    self.execute_callback(goal)
  File "/home/user/catkin_ws/src/real_robot/scripts/action_server.py", line 51, in callback
    print(self.xOdom)
AttributeError: 'move_turtle' object has no attribute 'xOdom'
```

Here is my code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python


from math import degrees, sqrt
import rospy
import actionlib
import numpy as np

from real_robot.msg import OdomRecordAction, OdomRecordResult, OdomRecordFeedback
from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry
from geometry_msgs.msg import Point32
from tf.transformations import euler_from_quaternion

odom_record_data=Point32()

class move_turtle(object):
    
    # create messages that are used to publish feedback and results
    _result = OdomRecordResult()
    _feedback = OdomRecordFeedback()

    def __init__(self):
        # creates the action server
        self._as = actionlib.SimpleActionServer("record_odom", OdomRecordAction, self.callback, False)
        self._as.start()
        self.ctrl_c = False
        self.rate = rospy.Rate(1)
        self.subodom = rospy.Subscriber('/odom', Odometry, self.call_record_odom)

    def call_record_odom(self,data):

        self.xOdom = data.pose.pose.position.x
        self.yOdom = data.pose.pose.position.y
        self.thOdom = data.pose.pose.orientation.z

    def callback(self,goal):

        rospy.loginfo("executing odometry record")
        i=0
        distance = 0
        dist_x = np.array((1, ), dtype = float)
        dist_y = np.array((1, ), dtype = float)
        orient_z = np.array((1, ), dtype = float)
        lap=100

        flag=False

        while distance<=lap:

            #calc traveled distance
            print(self.xOdom)
            dist_x= np.append(dist_x,self.xOdom)
            dist_y = np.append(dist_y,self.yOdom)
            orient_z = np.append(orient_z,self.thOdom)

            distance += sqrt( pow(dist_x[i] - dist_x[i-1], 2 ) + ( dist_y[i] - dist_y[i-1] )**2 ) 
            
            print("travelled distance:", distance)
            print(dist_x)
            
            # check that preempt (cancelation) has not been requested by the action client
            if self._as.is_preempt_requested():
                rospy.loginfo('The goal has been cancelled/preempted')
                # the following line, sets the client in preempted state (goal cancelled)
                self._as.set_preempted()
            

            # build and publish the feedback message
            self._feedback.current_total = distance
            self._as.publish_feedback(self._feedback)
            # the sequence is computed at 1 Hz frequency
            self.rate.sleep()
            flag=True
            i+=i

        if flag is True:
            self._result.list_of_odoms.x = dist_x
            self._result.list_of_odoms.y = dist_y
            self._result.list_of_odoms.z = orient_z

            self._as.set_succeeded(self._result.list_of_odoms)
            rospy.loginfo("Returning odometry values")

      
if __name__ == '__main__':
  rospy.init_node('Odom_record_node')   
  move_turtle()
  rospy.spin()
```

I dont understand whats the error telling me.

I would like to know first whats the meaning of the error.

second, I would like to append the xOdom data into the dist_x variable for each sensor reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because your action is being called *before* your subscriber. This is because the subscriber is what actually creates the attribute that gets used in the action callback. If you have someone publish on the topic *before* the action is called the code will work fine. However, you should instead make sure your odom attributes are initialized in `__init__` and **before** you set up a subscriber or action callback like so:

```
def __init__(self):
    # creates the action server
    self.xOdom = None
    self.yOdom = None
    self.thOdom = None
    self._as = actionlib.SimpleActionServer("record_odom", OdomRecordAction, self.callback, False)
    self._as.start()
    self.ctrl_c = False
    self.rate = rospy.Rate(1)
    self.subodom = rospy.Subscriber('/odom', Odometry, self.call_record_odom)
```

Then you may have to check that the values are initialized before using them.

Answer (score 0):

> AttributeError: 'move_turtle' object has no attribute 'xOdom'

Means you are trying to reference the attribute xOdom of the move_turtle object, but that object doesn't have that attribute.

Line 51 is:

```
print(self.xOdom)
```

and it is, in fact, referencing the xOdom attribute.

Your xOdom attribute is only set by the call_record_odom method, so it looks like that method isn't working properly or isn't being called at all.

In fact, `move_turtle()` is not really a function call (move_turtle is a class).

It creates an instance of the move_turtle class, in other words an object.

This triggers the `__init__(self)` method, which does call call_record_odom and callback, but in the wrong order.

```
    self._as = actionlib.SimpleActionServer("record_odom", OdomRecordAction, self.callback, False)
    self._as.start()
    self.ctrl_c = False
    self.rate = rospy.Rate(1)
    self.subodom = rospy.Subscriber('/odom', Odometry, self.call_record_odom)
```

Notice how `callback` (which requires `xOdom`) is called before `call_record_odom` (which sets `xOdom`)? That's why it doesn't work. When the code reaches the `callback` method (and its print), `xOdom` is not yet defined, and when you try to print it it returns an AttributeError because, indeed, the `move_turtle` object has no attribute `xOdom`.

Comment: `__init__` doesn’t call either of those methods. OPs problem is a publisher is publishes before the action server is called.